# Bitcoin Cash to CoPay Bitcoin Wallet - How to Recover?

Tags: copay

We have an eCommerce website and a customer is purchasing an item using Bitcoin.

We provided the customer with our business Copay Wallet address, however the customer sent "Bitcoin Cash" - how can he, or we, recover his payment?  The Copay wallet is of course Bitcoin only.

Comment: You can export the private key for that address from copay and import it into a wallet such as Electron Cash.

Comment: Out of interest, did he/she send the correct amount in FIAT worth, or just 1-for-1 coins in BCH?  Sounds like either (a) scammer trying to get you to accept BCH (1/6th the value) as bitcoin, (b) sneaky attempt to get you to consider accepting BCH (if you don't already), or (c) clueless, probably cause by the "bch is bitcoin" movement.  They should thank you for being so accommodating, if you were using SegWit (I don't think Copay supports it) their funds wouldn't be recoverable at all.

Answer (score 1):

> **how can he recover his payment?**

He can't. Bitcoin Cash transactions are not reversible and generally cannot be cancelled.

> **how can we recover his payment?**

Create a Bitcoin Cash wallet using your Bitcoin private keys. Then refund him (less transactions fees, agreed handling fees etc)

Given that this involves putting your private keys into an unfamiliar piece of software, there are security issues (you need to be sure you trust it and obtained it from the right place and know how to use it properly etc) there may be significant man-time costs that some businesses may be reluctant to commit to help a small one-time customer.

Answer (score 1):

To recover Bitcoin Cash (BCH) from a Bitpay/Copay BTC wallet, please follow the steps below:

1. Within the Bitpay/Copay app, navigate to `Settings`.
2. Under `Preferences`, tap on `Bitcoin Cash`.
3. Tap on `Scan wallets for BCH`, and to the right of the BTC wallet you want to duplicate, and tap on `Duplicate`.

Duplicating the BTC wallet will create a BCH wallet in your BitPay or Copay app with the BCH balance.

The option above to `duplicate` is not available for multi-sig BTC wallets, and you will need to use the [recovery tool](https://bitpay.github.io/copay-recovery/) to recover BCH funds sent to a multi-sig BTC wallet.